# "Server terminated early with status 127" when running node.js on Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver

I'm running a piece of Typescript code using Selenium and get **Server terminated early with status 127** when call executeScript. Other similar posts suggested to install Java, I already installed Java 20. chromedriver and chrome also have the same version as log stated. Please suggest solution for this issue, really appreciate all your help.

```
import * as chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';
import { Builder } from 'selenium-webdriver';

async function execute(url: string): Promise<string> {
  const options = new chrome.Options().headless();
  options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
  const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();

  driver.get(url);

  console.log(`Finish Initializing options and driver ... `)

  const response: string = await driver.executeScript(
    'const msg = "Hallo, world!"; console.log(`${msg}`); return `${msg}`'
  );
  console.log(`Execute script successfully ... `)
  await driver.quit();
  return response;
}

async function call() {
  const response = await execute("https://google.com");
  console.info(`Response: ${response}`)
}

call()
```

The error log:

```
Selenium Manager binary found at /home/work/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/bin/linux/selenium-manager
Driver path: /home/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chromedriver
Browser path: /home/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chrome
Finish Initializing options and driver ...
Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 127
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who face the same issue. Server terminated early with status 127 in Chrome generally due to missing some dependency libs.

Try to run your Chrome to check which libs are missing will solve this issue.